# SectionedFetchRequest it's not ordered correctly in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm creating an app to record expenses. I have made a SectionedFetchRequest by day. But here I have a problem:

The order in each sections does not seem to be correct. It orders the expenses from the oldest one to the new one, when the ideal would be the other way around. See the image for better clarification.

Image that show the incorrect order:

[image]

As you can see in the image the order is:

1, 2, 3, 4 when it should be 4, 3, 2, 1 from top to bottom.

If I change the ascending part to "true" in the SectionedFetchRequest, then the order of each section is correct, but the entire list is in the wrong order (the oldest expenses are shown first and should be the other way around.)

Code:

```
struct LogListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @SectionedFetchRequest(entity: ExpenseLog.entity(), sectionIdentifier: \.date, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExpenseLog.date, ascending: false)]) var logs: SectionedFetchResults<Date?, ExpenseLog>
    
    @State var logToEdit: ExpenseLog?
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach((logs), id: \.id) { section in
                Section(header: Text(dateFormatter.string(from: section[0].date!))) {
                    ForEach(section.filter({
                        self.searchText.isEmpty ? true :
                        $0.name!.localizedStandardContains(self.searchText)
                    })) { log in
                        Button {
                            logToEdit = log
                        } label: {
                            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                                CategoryIconsView(category: log.categoryEnum)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                    Text(log.nameText).font(.subheadline)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                Text(log.typeTransaction != "expensive" ? log.amountText : "-\(log.amountText)").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(log.typeTransaction == "income" ? .green : .primary)
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        }
                        .swipeActions(content: {
                            Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                                deleteTodo(log: log)
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .sheet(item: $logToEdit, onDismiss: {
            self.logToEdit = nil
        }) { (log: ExpenseLog) in
            AddLogView(name: log.name ?? "", amount: log.amount , category: Category(rawValue: log.category ?? "") ?? .food, date: log.date ?? Date(), logToEdit: log)
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: What type is `ExpenseLog.date`? If it is of type `Date` then does it contain time info as well or has that been cleared (set to midnight)?

Comment: It's a Date type but it has been set to midnight because I only need the day info. So every transaction is something like: 2022-08-09 00:00:00.0000

Comment: Fine but what do you want to sort on inside each section?

Comment: I want to sort every transaction made on each day (one section per day), from newest to oldest.

Comment: But how??? Using what property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just be seeing the wrong section name, try:

```
Section(header: Text(section.id, formatter:dateFormatter)) {
```

(FYI you must move your `dateFormatter` to outside the struct so it is a global. Initing objects inside `View` structs that are init many times is considered a memory leak)

I noticed you are sectioning by date so you probably only want to section based on the day without time. You can fix that with a computed property in your `ExpenseLog` class, e.g.

```
class ExpenseLog: NSManagedObject {
    @objc var dayDate: Date {
        let timeInterval = floor(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / 86400) * 86400
        return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval)
    } 
    ...
```

Then you can do `sectionIdentifier: \.dayDate`.

I also noticed your searching isn't quite right, should be something like this:

```
.onChange(searchText) { newSearchText in
    if newSearchText == "" {
        logs.nsPredicate = nil
    else {
        logs.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", newSearchText) 
    }
}
```

So now you can have the correct `ForEach(section) { log in` rather than the manual filtering.

Note there currently is a major flaw in `@FetchRequest` that if `LogListView` is re-init by a parent view its predicate is lost so you have to take that into consideration, e.g. wrap it in a sub View that never changes.

You probably also want to dynamically change the sort order, for that I recommend watching [Bring Core Data concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI from WWDC 2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10017/) however some of his SwiftUI code is ropey, e.g. a custom `Binding` instead of using `onChange` as I did above. If you use the Developer app to watch you can easily copy the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying! But I have a problem with the computed property dayDate. I have added the computed property to ExpensesLog Class and in the sectionIdentifier. But when I run the app it crash with the error: Thread 1: "[<ExpenseLog 0x600003aeaad0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity ExpenseLog is not key value coding-compliant for the key \"(null)\"." Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: It should be marked @objc sorry for the delay

Comment: This has solved my problem and much more. Thank you!